# What are words to express your nose, ears, eyes' ability?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

What are words to express your nose, ears and eyes' ability?

Can we use "**clear**", "**sharp**", "**delicate**", "**keen**" to express our eyes and ears' ability?, for example,

- "my eyes are so clear that I can see better than anyone"
- "my ears are so sharp that I can hear better than anyone"
- "my ears are so delicate that I can hear better than anyone"
- "I have such keen eyes/ears/nose that I can see/hear/smell better than anyone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must consider that adjectives that refer to eyes, noses, and ears most often refer to the physical organ and not to that organ's associated sense.

- Eyes are the organ but *Eyesight* or *Vision* is the sense.
- Nose is the organ but *Sense of Smell* is the sense.
- Ears are the organs but *Hearing* is the sense.

That being said, speakers often do substitute the organ for the sense and then apply a very limited number of adjectives to indicate they reference the sense and not the organ.  If you can apply an adjective to the sense, such as a *keen sense of smell*, you can usually apply the adjective to the organ and have it be understood.

- Sense of Smell - Good (and most of its synonyms), Keen, Refined, Sensitive, Powerful.  All work with *Nose* and retain their meaning. A *Sharp Nose*, however, might be understood as physically describing the nose as being pointed.
- Hearing - Good (and most of its synonyms), Keen, Acute, Powerful.  All work with *Ears* and retain their meaning.
- Vision - Good (and most of its synonyms), Sharp, Keen, Acute, Powerful.  All work with *Eyes* and retain their meaning. *Clear Eyes*, however, might be understood as describing the physical eye and would most likely mean something like *sober*.

Answer (score 0):

#### Aside from "delicate", these are mostly correct.

As a native speaker, I would say "keen" and "sharp" are both adjectives that are used to refer to the acuity of a physical sense. "Clear vision" is an idiom that refers to vision metaphorically, in regards to things like predicting the future or deciding the course of a company, rather than referring to literal vision of light with your eyes.

I'll also note that bragging this way may be received negatively, especially if you're bragging about having clear vision in a metaphorical sense.

With regards to "delicate", I would say that using it that way would be unusual. Sounds can be soft and delicate, but when you use it to refer to a part of your body such as your ears, you'd be referring to physical fragility of that body part - either because the body part is slim and easily broken, or because it's painfully sensitive to the touch. For instance, you might say "Don't touch my ears please. They're delicate because they were sunburned."